# How to show which element of function is being processed in r purrr map

Tags: r, dictionary, purrr, seq

I want to have a function that as part of it, shows me which element of the entire list of elements that it is working, to show the progress of the function over my list. I know how to do that using a for loop where my input is related to the number position of the element in a vector, but how can I do it using purrr:map?

```
x = c('a', 'b', 'c')

for(i in 1:length(x)) {
  print(paste0(i, '/', length(x), ' complete'))
}
```

Comment: `pbapply:: pblapply` provides a version with progress bar. Might you are interested.

Comment: thanks! I actually have the progress bar also built in to this that shows the % but I specifically want to know the position of the element of total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsophisticated but you could try `imap()` or `pmap()`:

```
library(purrr)

mods <- mtcars %>%
  split(.$cyl) %>%
  imap(~ {Sys.sleep(3) ; mod <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .x); cat(.y, "cyl complete\n"); return(mod)})  

4 cyl complete
6 cyl complete
8 cyl complete
```

Or:

```
dat <- mtcars %>%
  split(.$cyl)

mods <-
  pmap(list(dat, seq_along(dat), length(dat)), ~ {
    Sys.sleep(3)
    mod <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = ..1)
    cat(..2, "/", ..3, "complete\n")
    return(mod)
  })

1 / 3 complete
2 / 3 complete
3 / 3 complete
```

Comment: Great! That's what I'm looking for. Could you just help with modifying to my example where I don't have a formula like you inserted? If I use `imap(x, ~cat(paste0(.y, '/', length(x), ' complete\n')))`, I get 3 lines as I want them, showing "1/3 complete 2/3 complete 3/3 complete" but then I get 3 lines that show: [[1]] NULL [[2]] NULL [[3]] NULL. How do I need to edit to get rid of the NULL outputs?

Comment: `NULL` occurs because `imap()` isn't returning anything (i.e. in the example it's doing nothing but calling `cat()`.  Include the function that is processing `x` as part of `imap()` and assign the output.